# How can I position the html column of mine in css?

Tags: html, css

I am currently building my hs project, I'm just a beginner and I am struggling with this column like I want my bio looks like this one (below)
[image]

But I can't really do achieve this, this is my HTML and CSS code

html :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="photos.png" style="width: 320px;">
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="david">
        <h1>David Watson</h1>
        <h2></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS code for that

css:

```
.column {
  float: left;
}

.row {
     margin-left: 350px;
     margin-top: 100px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */


h1 {
    font-weight: 10;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

and btw this is how it works
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use
`.row{ display:flex }`

then the child element will take side by side position you can have a quick look on this too https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```
.row {
      display:flex
     margin-left: 350px;
     margin-top: 100px;
}
.column {
  margin:0 2rem;

}


h1 {
    font-weight: 10;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: but how can i do the one which is the name david and the email so close? like be close to each other

Comment: wrap all the left part inside a div and the right part in a div

Comment: remove the float left from column